# Powershell remote no standard output

Tags: c#, powershell, remote-access

I'm using a PowerShell object in C# to execute a remote command.  The sample command I want to get the value of is `Get-ExecutionPolicy`, but no standard output is returned.

The final goal is to get remaining disk space on a remote instance.

Here's the code I'm using to execute scripts remotely.  It works fine, quietly executes all tests as expected, outputs errors and exceptions, but...no standard output.  Can anyone help?

```
PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
logger.LogAndDisplay(Logger.MessageType.Note, "Connecting to '" + instance0 + "'");
logger.LogAndDisplay(Logger.MessageType.Note, "Executing script on remote: '" + path0 + "'.");
ps.AddScript("$password = convertto-securestring -asplaintext -force -string " + pass);
ps.AddScript("$credential = new-object -typename system.management.automation.pscredential -argumentlist " + user + ", $password");
ps.AddScript("$session = new-pssession " + instance0 + " -credential $credential");
ps.AddScript("Invoke-Command -Session $session -FilePath " + path0);
ps.AddScript("Remove-PSSession $session");
Execute(ps);
```

---

```
private bool Execute(PowerShell ps0)
{
    bool success = true;

    PSOutput.Clear();
    PSOutput = ps0.Invoke();

    if (ps0.HadErrors)
    {
        success = false;
        PSDataCollection<ErrorRecord> PSErrors = ps0.Streams.Error;
        foreach (ErrorRecord e in PSErrors)
        {
            logger.LogAndDisplay(Logger.MessageType.Note, e.ToString());
        }
    }

    if (PSOutput.Count() > 0)
    {
        logger.LogAndDisplay(Logger.MessageType.Subheader, "Command output:");
    }

    foreach (PSObject outputItem in PSOutput)
    {
        if (outputItem != null)
        {
            logger.LogAndDisplay(Logger.MessageType.Note, outputItem.BaseObject.GetType().FullName);
            logger.LogAndDisplay(Logger.MessageType.Note, outputItem.BaseObject.ToString() + "\n");
        }
    }

    logger.LogAndDisplay(Logger.MessageType.Note, "Command complete. Disconnecting.");
    ps0.Dispose();
    return success;
}
```

Comment: Where are you getting the `$session` variable in the powershell code? And why use `Invoke-Command` from powershell instead of using a remote runspace to begin with? I don't use runspaces a lot so I'm not just asking rhetorically.

Comment: @briantist - `$session` is set in the previous lines with a password and a username...it works fine, I definitely connect to and execute on the remote  instance.  I've never used a runspace, I'll do some research now.  But a lot of the current project uses PS to remote, so a solution around PS would be best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was this line:

```
ps.AddScript("Remove-PSSession $session");
```

> The Remove-PSSession cmdlet closes Windows PowerShell sessions
>   (PSSessions) in the current session. It stops any commands that are
>   running in the PSSessions, ends the PSSession, and **releases the
>   resources that the PSSession was using.** If the PSSession is connected
>   to a remote computer, Remove-PSSession also closes the connection
>   between the local and remote computers.

(emphasis mine)

Apparently, this includes the streams.

I stumbled across [ths interesting](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2014/03/30/understanding-streams-redirection-and-write-host-in-powershell.aspx) post about PowerShell output during my search that could answer some future questions too.